# Service broker timeout and error handling

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I've looked by I couldn't find out what happens to conversations when one side has an issue and how to handle it.  I think I've seen a few times when there was an error in the TargetService and it caused another error to occur.

I have a stored procedure which begins a conversation and sends a `RequestMessage` to a `TargetQueue` associated with a `TargetService` and a contract.  It then waits for up to 5 seconds to receive a message with that conversation handle on the `InitiatorQueue`.

Meantime an application on another server is waiting in a loop to receive messages on the `TargetQueue`, process them calling yet another system, and sending a `ResponseMessage` to the `InitiatorQueue`.

***Timeout***

Since the stored procedure should be responsive it waits at most 5 seconds because a user is waiting for a response.  If the application takes longer than 5 seconds to send a response, it goes ahead and ends the conversation.  When the application finally succeeds it will send the response to the `InitiatorQueue` and end it's side of the conversation.

So what happens to that `ResponseMessage` in the `InitiatorQueue`?  Does it have to be cleaned up somehow?  Since the requestor only ever listens for a response with the same conversation handle, it will never be received.  Will it be deleted when the 60 second lifetime I have specified for the dialog expires?

***Error***

So what if the application has a critical error and crashes (or the server goes down) while there is a message in the `TargetQueue`?  The initiator will close their side of the conversation, and the 60 second lifetime for the dialog will elapse.  Will everything be cleaned up?

What if the message has been received from the `TargetQueue` and the error occurs before a response is sent.  Will that dialog remain out there?

Just doing some testing, there doesn't seem to be a way to tell when I receive a message on `TargetQueue` if the dialog has been closed by the sender yet.  This leads to the application processing the `RequestMessage` and erroring out on the SEND to the `InitiatorQueue`.  Could/Should I attempt a receive on `TargetQueue` and close the dialog a second time in the stored procedure to clear the queue before I return a timeout error?